# R problems looping through array

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to loop through an array, by which in the end I will create a powercurve showing the power by a function of the number of animals per treatment and the mean difference between the two treatments

```
N=30                # number of maximum simulations per K
K=seq(10,30,1)      # maximum number of animals per group
ES=seq(1,2,0.1)     # mean difference compared to control

x=array(data=NA, 
        dim=c(N,length(K),length(ES)), 
        dimnames =list(paste("Sim",1:N, sep=""),
                       paste("Total Number of Animals=",min(K):max(K), sep=""),
                       ES))  # 3-dimensional matrix in which to store the values
for (q in ES){
  for (j in K){
    for (i in 1:N){
      controle<-rnorm(j,popmeansum$V3, 1.490918)
      new<-rnorm(j,popmeansum$V3-q, 1.490918)
      fit<-t.test(controle, new, alternative ="greater") 
      x[i,j,q]<-fit$p.value
    }
  }
}
```

The error i get is :

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, q, value = 0.00490665200011608) :
>   subscript out of bounds

My gut feeling says I am making a simple and stupid mistake. Unfortunately, those mistakes can take hours. Hope anyone sees a quick and simple fix.

Comment: My gut feeling says that you don't need a three-dimension loop. Instead use the vectorized power of R. Unfortunatly I can't help you as you did not included some reproducible data and an expected output.

Comment: Hi, the data you can use as it is a simulation from scratch, expect for the mean in the rnorm function. I am looking into this more and my knowledge of the array is limited as calling by the array and looking at it does not provide equal numbers. By my knowledge, an array is (row, column, matrix)

Comment: Your problem is that `ES`, and hence `q`, includes fractional values.  Hence you can't use it as an index in the final line of your loop.  You probably just need `q in 1:length(ES)` for your loop, and `ES[q]` in the line defining `new`.

Comment: what is `popmeansum`?

Comment: Still no luck following you help Andrew Gustar. Perhaps also strangs that the loop only starts filling after then tenth column.. popmeansum is a variable i made that enters the mean for the random variable

Comment: It will only fill from the tenth column because your `j` loop only starts at 10.  Also, you are using `popmeansum$V3` as a vector that may be of a different length from `j` and so may be recycled.  Or is it of length 1, in which case you might need `popmeansum$V3[1]` instead?

Comment: so, from what I can see, it has more to do with me trying to label many things in a few ways (K, ES, N) and as a result i am asking the loop to fill in numbers where there is no space?

Comment: I've posted an answer correcting the various problems.  You weren't far off - it is just that the indexing was not pointing where you thought it was!

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew!! This is exactly what i expected after your initial comment, but would have taken me considerable time to figure out. That is the ying/yang thing about coding. A lot of freedom, but you need to know were to look!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various problems here, but hopefully this will help solve some of them...

```
N=30                # number of maximum simulations per K
K=seq(10,30,1)      # maximum number of animals per group
ES=seq(1,2,0.1)     # mean difference compared to control

x=array(data=NA, 
        dim=c(N,length(K),length(ES)), 
        dimnames =list(paste("Sim",1:N, sep=""),
                       paste("Total Number of Animals=",min(K):max(K), sep=""),
                       ES))  # 3-dimensional matrix in which to store the values

#all OK to here
#in the next loop, popmeansum$V3 is not defined.  If it is a single value, then I suggest...
pms <- popmeansum$V3[1]

for (q in 1:length(ES)){ #keep q as integers so that you can use it for indexing
  for (j in 1:length(K)){ #to be consistent with your dimensions of x
    for (i in 1:N){
      controle<-rnorm(K[j],pms,1.490918)
      new<-rnorm(K[j],pms-ES[q],1.490918)
      fit<-t.test(controle, new, alternative ="greater") 
      x[i,j,q]<-fit$p.value
    }
  }
}
```

It is not the slickest piece of code but it does at least do something!